# Cart rule in magento2?

Tags: magento2.2, shopping-cart-price-rules, php-7

I have created a cart price rule which contains specfic coupon and percentage of product price discount(10%).

How to checkflow of Magento apply these rule.

Comment: Take a look at: `vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Quote/Discount.php`.

Comment: Where to process discount amt calculation.

Answer (score 1):

First check on which websites, which customers group you used in that rule. then check conditions and actions for your rule.

After that, you add the product to the cart and check `checkout/cart` page. If cart price rule is applying for this product that you can see discount is applied to the product and you see in a summary also.

Please see below screenshot, I create one cart rule and it is applied to a product when product price greater than 100 and I applied 10$ fixed amount discount.

[image]

In your case, after adding the product to cart, you add coupon code in `checkout/cart` page. After adding this code your rule work and see a discount label in summary also.

[image]

I hope this will help you.

Comment: How to check core process(calculation of discount amt).Because i want to set new  rule for shopping cart .

Comment: Means you have two cart price rule or a single cart price rule.

Comment: I want to know about some details. How to magento calculate discount amt.I want to customise that

Comment: As per your cart rule, Magento gets value from that rule and process your rule. and also you calculate manually your rule and check price.

Comment: Yes @Dhaduk Mitesh.I want  to customise these flow.So can u help me to find out which file these  calculation/process going on.

Comment: Please check : `/vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/RulesApplier.php`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75384/discussion-between-dhaduk-mitesh-and-priya-m).